# go-redis ZRange error "redis: can't parse array/set/push reply" and redis: invalid reply: "\r\n"

Tags: go, redis, go-redis

I'm getting error while using ZRange via go-redis.

```
clusterOption := &redis.ClusterOptions{
    DialTimeout:  ev.Redis.DialTimeout,
    ReadTimeout:  ev.Redis.ReadTimeout,
    WriteTimeout: ev.Redis.WriteTimeout,
    PoolSize:     ev.Redis.PoolSize,
    PoolTimeout:  ev.Redis.PoolTimeout,
    MinIdleConns: ev.Redis.MinIdleConnections,
    MaxRedirects: ev.Redis.MaxRedirects,
    Addrs:        []string{ev.Redis.Address},
    TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
        MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12,
    },
}

redisClient := redis.NewClusterClient(clusterOption)
if err := redisClient.Ping(ctx).Err(); err != nil {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("pinging failed, %s", err.Error())
}
ids, err := redisClient.ZRange(context.Background(), "x:123", 0, -1)
```

There are two errors.

1. redis: can't parse array/set/push reply: "$24"
2. redis: invalid reply: "\r\n"

The number of elements in the sorted set is 21028 for first error and 475490 for second error.

I'm using AWS MemoryDB Redis cluster.

Number of nodes: 9

Number of shards: 3

Redis version: 7.0

Golang version: go 1.21.1

go-redis version: v9.3.0

What could be the reason?